# regex to extract first number with decimals in string

Tags: javascript, regex

From the following types of strings, I want to extract the first decimal number without any signs etc.

```
$9.12 per 1Kg
$8.91/KG
```

should yield

```
9.12
8.91
```

etc.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? `string.match(/\$(\d\.\d+)/);`

Comment: `([0-9])\.([0-9])\w` but I'm not sure

Comment: Basic regular expression... /\d+\.\d+/ [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%2F)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex and grab captured group #1 (array #1 from `String#match`):

```
^\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qH4hI0/1)

Comment: Could you provide adjustment such that the sign is also captured? I tried adding `\-?` before `\d+` but this conflucts with `^\D`, which contains `\-`. Thank you